# Changing cell formatting in Google Sheet running PHP

Tags: php, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I have a PHP program creating, loading data, and formatting a Google Sheet...  It all works fine except for some of my formatting script.  The cell color and bolding formatting are working fine...  The number formatting is not and creates an error unless I comment it out...  I do not see an obvious formatting problem in it and it has totally stumped me...

The offending code section...

```
$format = [
    'backgroundColor' => [
         'red' => $r,
         'green' => $g,
         'blue' => $b,
         'alpha' => $a,
    ],
      'textFormat' => [
      'bold' => true
    ],
// I have to comment out the section below for the script to run
       'userEnteredFormat' => [
       'numberFormat' => [
         'type' => 'NUMBER',
         'pattern' => '#,##0.0000'
       ]
     ]
// End of offending setion
];
```

Overall section dealing with formatting

```
// get sheetId of sheet with index 0
$sheetId = $service->spreadsheets->get($spreadsheetId);
$sheetId = $sheetId->sheets[0]->properties->sheetId;

// set colour to a medium gray
$r = $g = $b = 0.9;
$a = 1;

// define range
$myRange = [
    'sheetId' => $sheetId, // IMPORTANT: sheetId IS NOT the sheets index but its actual ID
    'startRowIndex' => 5,
    'endRowIndex' => 10,
    'startColumnIndex' => 4, // can be omitted because default is 0
    'endColumnIndex' => 6,
];

// define the formatting, change background colour and bold text
$format = [
    'backgroundColor' => [
         'red' => $r,
         'green' => $g,
         'blue' => $b,
         'alpha' => $a,
    ],
      'textFormat' => [
      'bold' => true
    ],
       'userEnteredFormat' => [
       'numberFormat' => [
         'type' => 'NUMBER',
         'pattern' => '#,##0.0000'
       ]
     ]
];

// build request
$requests = [
    new Google_Service_Sheets_Request([
        'repeatCell' => [
            'fields' => 'userEnteredFormat.backgroundColor, userEnteredFormat.numberFormat, userEnteredFormat.textFormat.bold',
            'range' => $myRange,
            'cell' => [
                'userEnteredFormat' => $format,
            ],
        ],
    ])
];

// add request to batchUpdate
$batchUpdateRequest = new Google_Service_Sheets_BatchUpdateSpreadsheetRequest([
  'requests' => $requests
]);

// run batchUpdate
$result = $service->spreadsheets->batchUpdate($spreadsheetId, $batchUpdateRequest);
```

Answer (score 0):

When I saw your script, I thought that it is required to modify the part of `numberFormat`. So, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
$format = [
    'backgroundColor' => [
         'red' => $r,
         'green' => $g,
         'blue' => $b,
         'alpha' => $a,
    ],
      'textFormat' => [
      'bold' => true
    ],
       'userEnteredFormat' => [
       'numberFormat' => [
         'type' => 'NUMBER',
         'pattern' => '#,##0.0000'
       ]
     ]
];
```

#### To:

```
$format = [
  "backgroundColor" => [
    "red" => $r,
    "green" => $g,
    "blue" => $b,
    "alpha" => $a,
  ],
  "textFormat" => [
    "bold" => true,
  ],
  "numberFormat" => [
    "type" => "NUMBER",
    "pattern" => "#,##0.0000",
  ],
];
```

- When this modification is reflected in your script, the background color, text format, and the number format of cells "E6:F10" are updated.

#### Reference:

- https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#updatecellsrequest